# How to get inputbox parameters in vba

Tags: excel, vba, cell, inputbox

I have a trivial problem. I need to easily get each range parameter as a variable in msgbox. i can try to get this target using mid or left from range.adress, but the range can be variable, I have to do "if" depending on the length of the numbers and letters in the range. Is there any easy way to get the variables a, b, e, f?
Thank you in advance.

```
  Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim cell As CellFormat
  
  Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
  MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address

 
  f = rng.Address
  MsgBox f 'example: $P$11:$T$15


rng.Address = Range(cell(a, b), cell(e, f)) ' 
MsgBox a 'value a
MsgBox b 'value b
MsgBox e 'value e
MsgBox f 'value f
    
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do with these variables?

Comment: `a` is `rng.cells(1).Row` and `b` is `rng.cells(1).Column`  Similarly for `rng.cells(rng.cells.count).Row/Column`  That's assuming a rectangular single-area range was selected.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are trying to set the value of `rng.Address`, which is not allowed, so it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
Sub RangeSelectionPrompt_sample()

Dim A As Range, B As Range
Set A = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
Set B = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
ActiveSheet.Range(A.Address & ":" & B.Address).Select

Dim c As Long, d As Long, e As Long, f As Long
c = InputBox("First Line")
d = InputBox("First Column")
e = InputBox("Last Line")
f = InputBox("Last Column")
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(c, d), ActiveSheet.Cells(e, f)).Select
End Sub
```

If you want too see (use too debug.print):

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(c, d), ActiveSheet.Cells(e, f)).Address
```

Answer (score 0):

@Julio Gadioli Soares answer is correct when you want to specify the range by entering the parameters. This is an opposite way to get the range parameters of an existing range:

The address of the top left cell of a range is: `rng.Resize(1, 1).Address`, and the row and column numbers are `rng.Row` and `rng.Column`.

The address of the bottom right cell of a range is: `rng.Item(rng.Count).Address`, similarly the row and column numbers are `rng.Item(rng.Count).Row` and `rng.Item(rng.Count).Column`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. After a few days of break, I came up with a new idea and solved. This code can help someone in need. THX!

```
Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()

  Dim rng As Range



  On Error Resume Next


  Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
  
If rng = "" Then Exit Sub
  
  
InputBoxRes = rng.Address  ' example "$A$1:$KJ$55"



LeftRange = Left(InputBoxRes, InStr(Replace(InputBoxRes, ":", "*"), "*") - 1)
LeftReplace = Replace(LeftRange, "$", "#", 2)

A_Parameter = Left(LeftReplace, InStr(Replace(LeftReplace, "#", "*"), "*") - 1)
B_Parameter = Replace(LeftReplace, A_Parameter & "#", "")


    MsgBox A_Parameter 'A
    MsgBox B_Parameter '1


RightRange = Replace(InputBoxRes, LeftRange & ":", "")
LeftReplaceLeft = Replace(RightRange, "$", "#", 2)

C_Parameter = Left(LeftReplaceLeft, InStr(Replace(LeftReplaceLeft, "#", "*"), "*") - 1)
D_Parameter = Replace(LeftReplaceLeft, C_Parameter & "#", "")


    MsgBox C_Parameter 'KJ
    MsgBox D_Parameter '55



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is simpler and the result is column numbers, not column letters. Both methods can come in handy. Thx.

```
  Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()
      
  Dim rng As Range
    
    
      Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
      
    
    MsgBox rng.Resize(1, 1).Address
    
        MsgBox rng.Column
        MsgBox rng.Row
    
    MsgBox rng.Item(rng.Count).Address
    
        MsgBox rng.Item(rng.Count).Column
        MsgBox rng.Item(rng.Count).Row
        
    End Sub
```